# Need to call gtk_init function, but not from main function - C++

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

Im using GTK3 to create something. In tutorials there is

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

gtk_window, gtk_container etc...
```

I want to create MainProgram that will be handling the drawings outside this main function. So I delete the code above and make a new one:

main.cpp

```
#include "MainProgram.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MainProgram mainProgram;
    mainProgram.run(); // the magic is now happening inside this run method
```

MainProgram.h

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "MainProgram.h"
class MainProgram
{
public:
    MainProgram();
    ~MainProgram();

    void run();

    void initSystems();
...other not so important code goes inside
```

finally, the MainProgram.cpp

```
#include "MainProgram.h"

MainProgram::MainProgram()
{
...
}

MainProgram::~MainProgram(){}


void MainProgram::run()
{   
// about that magic we were talking about
    initSystems();
}

void MainProgram::initSystems(){

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); // here it is. 

    _window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(_window), _screenWidth, _screenHeigth); 
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(_window), "Fill & stroke");
    // ************** FIX OF THE PROBLEM
    gtk_widget_show_all(_window); // DIDNT CALL
    gtk_main();                   // These two functions
}
```

Now when I do try and compile the program with:

```
g++ main.cpp MainProgram.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I get the following warning:

```
MainProgram.cpp: In member function ‘void MainProgram::initSystems()’:
MainProgram.cpp:22:12: error: ‘argc’ was not declared in this scope
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
            ^
MainProgram.cpp:22:19: error: ‘argv’ was not declared in this scope
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
```

Is there a simple way to pass those addresses from main function from main.cpp inside this? Im doing this to make my code look cleaner and trying not to overload the main.cpp file  :)

Comment: You will need to pass `argc` and `argv` all the way through to `MainSystem()`. Or just pass `NULL` for both arguments; all it does is make GTK+ check for its own set of command line arguments, and if you aren't intending on using the GLib API for that it'll just wreck things. Either way, the choice is yours. If you do not understand what any of this means, you will need to learn C++ before you can learn GTK+.

Comment: @andlabs What is MainSystem()? Can you tell me that?

Comment: That was a typo; I meant `initSystem()`.

Comment: @andlabs Ok, but should I pass the &argc, &argv in `MainProgram mainProgram(&argc, &argv)`, the overload constructor and make the way down to initSystem(), or I could pass them in `mainProgram.run(&argc, &argv)`?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put two functions to display my app, you can see in MainProgram.cpp file, I made markings. Its last few lines in that 'file'.